# Storing lines in an array

Tags: c, beginner, pointers

> Rewrite `readlines` to store lines in an array supplied by main, rather than calling `alloc()` to maintain storage. How much faster is the program?

Here is my solution:

```
int readlines(char **lineptr, char *storage, int maxlines, int storage_size) {

    int len;
    int nlines;

     nlines = 0;
     while((len = _getline(storage, MAXLEN))) {
        if(nlines >= maxlines || !(storage_size - len)) {
            return -1;
        }
         else {
            storage[len - 1] = '\0';
            lineptr[nlines] = storage;

            storage += len; // next free space in the buffer supplied by main 
            storage_size -= len;
            nlines++;
        }
    }
    return nlines;
}
```

Now, the function takes 2 more arguments: a pointer to the array that will store all the read lines and its size. There is no need now to use another array to store the line temporary, I just can pass portions of the `storage` to `getline`.

The condition `!(storage_size - len)` verifies if there is enough space in `storage` to store the line that was just read. At each iteration `storage` is incremented to point to the next free space in the array and the value of the variables `storage_size` is reduced.

(This exercise can be found at page 124 in K&R.)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I don't know what `_getline` is; perhaps it's something like [the file-input function described here](http://www.gnu.org/software/libc/manual/html_node/Line-Input.html).

---

This looks strange ...

```
int nlines;

nlines = 0;
```

I think that C now (like C++) allows you to delay defining a local variable until you initialize it. So there's no need to declare your variables at the top of the function.

---

Passing `MAXLEN` is probably wrong: because if `(MAX_LEN > storage_size)` then you give `_getline` the opportunity to write past the end of the buffer.

Allowing a buffer overrun is a bug.

Instead you could do something like:

```
int n_lines = 0;

for (;;)
{
    // define local buffer inside function
    char buffer[MAX_LEN];
    int line_length = _getline(buffer, MAXLEN);
    if (line_length == 0)
        break;
    if (n_lines >= maxlines)
        return -1;
    if (line_length > storage_size)
        return -1;
    buffer[line_length - 1] = '\0';
    // copy local buffer to passed-in buffer
    strcpy(storage, buffer);
    lineptr[n_lines] = storage;
    storage += line_length;
    storage_size -= line_length;
    ++n_lines;
}

return n_lines;
```

Or you can read directly into the passed-in buffer, to avoid `strcpy` and avoid defining `MAXLEN`:

```
int line_length = _getline(buffer, storage_size);
if (line_length == storage_size)
{
    // fail unless there's nothing more to read
    char temp[1];
    if (0 != _getline(temp, 1))
        return -1;
}
```

---

I'm not sure what this statement does ...

```
storage[len - 1] = '\0';
```

... if the end-of-line marker is a two-character "\r\n" sequence (which it is on Windows).

---

You could possibly edit your variable names; if you're going to use_underscores as you did for storage_size, then perhaps:

- maxlines -> max_lines
- len -> line_length
- lineptr -> lines or lines_array
- nlines -> num_lines or line_number or line_counter

The least obvious variable name was `len`.